# How to perform a meta regression in SPSS or R?

Tags: r, spss, meta-analysis, meta-regression, systematic-review

I am working on a systematic review looking at the global prevalence of pain, I am trying to do a meta regression to examine what effect gender, age, etc has on the prevalence of pain. I have no prior knowledge of regression analysis and I am struggling to figure out my next move, I can use either SPSS or r (prefer SPSS) i have 23 prevalence estimates, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Next move" after what?  Have you established criteria for your literature search?  Have you performed the search?  Just what step in the process are you at?

Comment: @whuber the OP does say she has 23 estimates so I assumed she had got at least that far.

Comment: @mdewey I thought so, too, until I reread the question and saw that the interest is on the effects of specific regressor variables.  To assess that, obviously much more is needed than just prevalence estimates.

Comment: This is a meta-analysis of prevalence/proportions (your data doesn't have a comparison group, right?).  This detailed, hands-on tutorial provides a step-by-step guide showing you how to conduct a full meta-analysis of proportions/prevalence, including meta-regression. Check out the tutorial here: https://youtu.be/2wbXTFvaRnM.

Answer (score 1):

You will need from each study an estimate of the prevalence and its standard error. You will probably want to transform them in some way. You do not say whether you have study level information on sex and age (just average age or proportion women) rather than individual level data. If you only have study level data you need to use software which does the meta-analysis appropriately. I do not know whether you can do this in SPSS but there are many packages available in R which do. My personal preference is for the `metafor` package. If you have individual level data then you can use a mixed effects regression.

There is a wealth of material on the author's website http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php which should help you get further with your analysis.